# is there any kind of reverse_iterator in List, just to reverse the List? (Java8 stream solution preferred)

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am wondering if there are some kind of reverse_iterator(like c++) in List implementation like `ArrayList<Integer>`. i.e, I would like to iterate from the end of the List rather than from the beginning?

Is there any Java8 stream solution?

Comment: All Standard java api classes are documented in Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, list.size()).map(i -> list.size() - i).mapToObj(list::get).iterator()`

Comment: maybe your answer is right, but could you explain, too long to be understandable. :-) @shmosel

Comment: Just use Guava's `Lists.reverse()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java there is List Iterator
https://www.journaldev.com/13457/java-listiterator

```
// Substitute appropriate type.
ArrayList<...> a = new ArrayList<...>();

// Add elements to list.

// Generate an iterator. Start just after the last element.
ListIterator li = a.listIterator(a.size());

// Iterate in reverse.
while(li.hasPrevious()) {
  System.out.println(li.previous());
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct, I would like to see if there is some elegant Java8 solution:-) let's wait for some more time

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could have reversed the list is to use `Collections.reverse`

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(); // assign some values here
a.forEach(System.out::println); // actual order
Collections.reverse(a);
a.forEach(System.out::println); // reverse order
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a option for reverse iteration in java.Below code works fine.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(1);
al.add(2);
al.add(3);
al.add(4);

ListIterator<Integer> itr = al.listIterator(al.size());

System.out.println("Printing from last element ");
while (itr.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println(itr.previous());
}
```